# SBT configuration failed to load in Typesafe Activator

Tags: sbt, typesafe-activator, play-slick

I'm currently trying to start a play-slick application through the Typesafe Activator, but it fails to load the SBT configuration and I get this error;

```
/play-slick/build.sbt:30: error: reference to fork is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import _root_.play.Project._
and import Keys._
fork in run := true
^
Type error in expression
Failed to load project.
```

Does this mean I have SBT downloaded twice and what can I do to resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: There might be _someone_ who can just look at this error and know what the problem is, but it isn't me. The application you're trying to start, is it on the net somewhere we can look at it? How would I reproduce this problem on my own computer?

Comment: Looks like you're getting some help on this (from someone more knowledgeable than I) at https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/1060

Comment: See my answer to [Can't Run Activator Template projects Activator UI Failed to load SBT configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155681/cant-run-activator-template-projects-activator-ui-failed-to-load-sbt-configurat/34347454#34347454).

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to say that I came across this exact same issue when trying to use the [Play-Slick example](https://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/play-slick) linked from the [Play Tutorials page](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Tutorials).

The solution to get it working seems to have indeed been to follow the suggestion in the [Github link](https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/1060) that Seth Tisue included in a comment above, where *corruptmemory* suggested removing the following line from build.sbt:

```
fork in run := true
```

In my case, this was enough to convince IntelliJ to open the project and let me tinker with it. (Just in case this is the first result for anyone else coming across this problem)

Answer (score 2):

just remove

```
fork in run := true
```

from build.sbt  and hit activator clean run from cmd