# Can't Run Activator Template projects Activator UI Failed to load SBT configuration

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

I am new to Play Framework and Scala and this amazing tool activator.

I am unable to run template projects that run play framework (eg: hello-play-scala) but able to run hello-scala (non playframework) well.

I am running activator 1.3.5

The error I get is :

```
H:\Project\PlayFrameworkTest\hello-play-java\build.sbt:12: error: reference to fork is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import _root_.play.Project._
and import Keys._
fork in run := true
^
Type error in expression
Failed to load project.
```

And the build.sbt is :

```
name := """hello-play-java"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.2.2", 
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "2.3.1")

playJavaSettings


fork in run := true
```

and Plugins.sbt is

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.2")
```

and the build.properties is

```
#Activator-generated Properties
#Fri Aug 21 23:24:51 NPT 2015
template.uuid=b7274e52-c226-4deb-bb0e-ab2fdb8f4767
sbt.version=0.13.2
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem on Windows 8.1, and after googling for a solution, I initially tried to update some of my plugins. (It turned out that only sbt-less was a bit out of date.) However, that did not resolve the matter.

So, I found a couple of Web pages that mentioned the same problem, and it seemed that folks who adjusted the number of forward slashes in their `~/.sbt/repositories` file (`C:/Users/<username>/.sbt/repositories` file on Windows) were able to resolve the matter that way. So, I changed both of the `file:////` patterns in my `~/.sbt/repositories` file to `file:///`.

Then I stopped my `activator`, killed all of the lingering instances of Java that it had spawned, deleted my `<project_directory>/RUNNING_PID` file and restarted `activator`. Now, things seem to be working.

FYI, here are the two most helpful pages that I found regarding the problem:

- [Activator UI: Failed to load sbt configuration (Windows)](https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/1037)
- [Cannot create new play-scala project, failed to load SBT configuration File](https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/1034)